# How to manage water runoff on flat roof of accessory dwelling unit

Tags: water, roof, backyard

I am planning to build a new accessory dwelling unit (granny flat) in my backyard. I really like this design from https://node.eco/

[image]

However how do I manage the flat roof water run off? Is it just very low pitch or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slope the surface of the roof to one corner - the black surround hides it.

The slope does not need to be much (0.5cm per metre or 1/4" per 3 feet roughly - my guess) but the roof should not have dips in it ie you should not get puddles after rain.

Then organise the downpipe as required.

Comment: How come the slope here is so low vs. Shed or regular house? Is this design only for region without snow or tree leaves falling? Because in Pacific Northwest, I collect 5 inches of leaves over Dec on the ground.

Comment: @HP.  So you think houses with a 60 degree sloping roof are designed for the rainfall? Roof designs tend to be down to what the local carpenters understood - which in some localities meant they used a ship construction upsidedown...